# Writing junk data to binary file

Tags: c++, file

I store useful data from a binary file which I need add to structures untill junk data appear ( when the first junk bit appears i stop loading the data to structures ). I need to write ( copy ) those junk data from the file ( which i do not store to structures ) to another file. How can I do that without allocating array for junk data and copying there  using `f1 . read ( junkArray, junkLen )` and then :

```
file . write ( junkArray , junkLen ) ;
```

I would like to do something like

```
file . write ( f1 , junkLen );
```

where f1 is file at positition where junk data starts.

Comment: Look at the method seekg

Comment: if the C++ tag is accurate, streams should be used instead of c FILE structs

Answer (score 0):

The website [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) has this canonical example of how seek, [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) and [write](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/) to files at specific positions -- for reading it is like this

```
// read a file into memory
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    // allocate memory:
    char * buffer = new char [length];

    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,length);

    is.close();

    // print content:
    std::cout.write (buffer,length);

    delete[] buffer;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Just replace the parameters in `seekg` with the position you actually want to read/write.

For writing, looks at [seekp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/)